# Counting the amount of tries it would take to generate a number in a 2D array

Tags: c, arrays

If I have to generate a 6 by 6 array with random integers between 0 to 10, how can you modify the code to tell the number of tries it would take for the diagonal in the array to contain numbers greater or equal to 6 and print the array. Can someone look at this code and tell me why this doesn't work

```
for (i = 0; i<6; ++i)
{
    for (j = 0; j<6; ++j)
    {
        if (i == j&&i>=6&&j>=6)
        {
          count++;
          printf("%d", array[i][j]);
          printf("%d", count);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't checking the entries in the diagonal to see if they are greater than or equal to 6, it's just checking i and j. Also i<6 and j<6 so the if statement will never execute (although like i said, you really want to be checking the numbers of the diagonal of the array instead of checking the indices).

Comment: would it help if I placed the if statement inside a while loop (i==j) to check if array[i][j] >= 6?

Answer (score 0):

The condition in your if statement should look like this:

```
if (i == j && array[i][j] >= 6)
```

As was mentioned above, the way your code works now it is only checking the value of the indices themselves, not the value of the array at the indices, which is what you want.